# Android url scheme in manifest

Tags: android, regex, android-manifest, url-scheme

I want to identify different urls and open it with specific activities.

I declare intent filter in manifest and it works if I use simple condition :

```
<data
    android:host="www.myhost.fr"
    android:pathPattern="/.*\\.shtml"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

If I want to distinguish key words like "story" and "video", I change my pathPattern like this.

Activity Story :

```
<data
    android:host="www.myhost.fr"
    android:pathPattern="/.*story\\.shtml"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

Activity Video :

```
 <data
    android:host="www.myhost.fr"
    android:pathPattern="/.*video\\.shtml"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

EDIT
Urls I try to intercept :

- Url story : http://www.myhost.fr/lot_of_useles_text4085280/story.shtml
- Url video : http://www.myhost.fr/lot_of_useles_text309434/video.shtml
- Url match : http://www.myhost.fr/lot_of_useles_text/match_mtc616710.shtml

The IDs arre before "/" for story and video. For match, it is different.

When I test this solution, the pattern is not recognized. If I test it in regex on web, it says it's correct.

Any idea ?

Comment: What url do you want to match exactly ?

Comment: I added them, thanks for noticing it

Comment: I'm not 100% sure so I won't create an answer, but you can try that : "/.*/video.shtml"

Comment: That is not working. First, you have to escape special characters you want to interpret, like ".". My first example is working. The problem happens when I try to use "word" to distinguish 2 different types of urls.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture ID and specific word with the .shtml included?

I tried with:

```
((\d+)/(story\.shtml|video\.shtml))|(match_mtc(\d+)\.shtml)
```

And that captures in groups the ID and key word if it is story or video, or just the ID if it is "match_mtc".

You'd probably have to double escape the characters in the regex for Java like this:

```
((\\d+)/(story\\.shtml|video\\.shtml))|(match_mtc(\\d+)\\.shtml)
```

You can then call the groups with $1,$2,...,$n and get the specific strings you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my question focus on manifest. Regex are extremely limited in manifest file. Our only solution has been to declare several data items like : <data android:host="www.host.fr" android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*/.*/story\\.shtml" android:scheme="http" /> (the others have less"/.*"). Hope it helps !